# Joomla "remember me" security risk

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

The default behavior of the Joomla 2.5 "Remember me" checkbox during login is to store a session cookie for 1 year.

I've come across this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-cms/PbiOxKzVR2A) of it being insecure. Is this the case with Joomla 2.5?

What are the best practices with this if it is insecure?

Comment: Why has somebody downvoted this question, it's actually very good and interesting topic

Comment: The risk of remember me as implemented is that a user's computerr is stolen or otherwise accessed and that the same user name and password is used on other sites. It's not a session cookie it's a presistent login cookie. There is currently a pull request in the feature tracker to make some improvements to this.

Comment: @Elin It sounds like more than that according to the Google groups discussion: `for every single request you make to that website in the future[whether or not you are logged in] - your browser sends your userid and password in almost cleartext across the network`. Is that really the case?

Comment: No. It only runs the remember me code if your session has expired. IT runs it once to authenticate you and then it's done and you are using sessions.